# Spring boot 2.3.12 release not working with H2 integration tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, integration-testing, h2

With Spring 2.1.3.Release, H2 integration tests were working fine.

Below is the configuration

Application Properties:

```
spring.application.name=someApp
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=NON_NULL
server.max-http-header-size=16000
```

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "writeEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "writeTransactionManager", basePackages = {
        "somepackage.repositories.write" })
public class H2DatabaseWriteConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private DatabaseConfiguration vDatabaseConfiguration;

    @Bean(name = "writeDataSource")
    public DataSource writeDataSource() throws CommonConfigDecryptException {
        String dbUrl = "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1";

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");
        dataSource.setUrl(dbUrl);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("spring.datasource.data", "data.sql");
        props.setProperty("spring.datasource.initialization-mode", "ALWAYS");
        dataSource.setConnectionProperties(props);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "writeEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                                                                       @Qualifier("writeDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("somepackage.models.jpa").persistenceUnit("write")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "writeTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager writeTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("writeEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory writeEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(writeEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

BootStrap:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: someApp
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  jackson:
    serialization:
      fail-on-empty-beans: false
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    generate-ddl: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        enable_lazy_load_no_trans: true
```

**The above configuration stopped working after upgrading spring boot version to 2.3.12.release.**

The error we see is

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "USERPROFILE" not found; SQL statement:
> insert into userProfile.....

When  test case starts, below are the logs,

```
Hibernate: create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
Hibernate: create table userProfile .....
```

so looks like tables are getting created.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it took some time but the issue was just dependency configuration.

I had to update the POM to use H2 jar that was working with previous execution, instead of the one that comes latest Spring boot parent package.

With Spring 2.1.3.Release, used 1.4.198. And all started working well.